# Consuming an Authorized Get method in Web API from Angular using bearer token gives error

Tags: typescript, authentication, webapi, bearer-token, angular13

I have a Web Application which has CRUD operations and is fetching data from SQL database using Entity framework.

I have authorized the action methods in Web API using [Authorize] attribute, and I have implemented token based authentication.

It is all working fine, but when I am trying to consume this API from angular method then I am getting error?

Actually I am very much receiving the bearer token from angular call to API, also I am storing this token in localstorage in Angular, but when I am adding this bearer token in header section using interceptors in angular then don't know it doesn't work and gives error as mentioned below

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:58480/api/values/get?id=7' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed.

I tried to add Header section through interceptor as I am able to receive the bearer token in Angular's localstorage, but it gives error.

I was expecting the output of get method call from API using bearer token as authentication check.

Code Sections below:

Get method in service class

```
GetEmployeeData(id):Observable<Employee>
  {
    
    console.log("get call has come");
    const headers={'content-type':'application/json'}
    
    return this.htobj.get<Employee>
    
    
    ('http://localhost:58480/api/values/get?id='+id,
      {'headers':headers,responseType:'json'});
      
      
  }
```

Get method while consuming in App module ts file

```
getfinal(){
    this.servobj.GetEmployeeData(7).pipe(  
      (map(responsedata=>{
       
        console.log(responsedata+ "gully");

        
        return responsedata;
  
       }//}
      
      ))).subscribe(rr=>
          {        
          console.log("is response");
           
      }    ,
            
      
      (error)=>{console.log("error")
     
    })}
```

Interceptor method to add bearer token in headers section for all httprequests

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
   
   
    const token = localStorage.getItem("val123");
    console.log(request);
    console.log("interceptor call" + token);
    if(!token)
    {
      console.log("inside token");
      return next.handle(request);

    }
    let rt="Bearer" + token;
    console.log(rt);
    const req1=request.clone({
      headers:request.headers.set("Authorization",rt),
    });
    console.log(req1)
    return next.handle(req1);
  }
}
```

[image: Getmethodcall_App_controller]

[image: Interceptor_code]

[image: Post_authorisation_header]

[image: Getmethod_service_class]

[image: Error_details]